# Swift Hide Button In Another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

Currently working on my first IOS application. I have a purchase button, on success this currently sets a test button on the same view controller to hidden. Code is as follows

Decleration

```
@IBOutlet weak var Test: UIButton!
```

hide button on successful purchase

```
 Test.isHidden = true
```

Now this works on my Test button, which is sat in the PurchaseViewController,class is the MasterViewController.Swift. (Purchase button that initiates this method is also in the same view controller)

PlanViewController also has a button, and class is also linked to MasterViewController.Swift. This has a separate button that i wish to hide on success of the purchase button.

When I utilise the same code as above for the button, it crashes, is their a limitation on manipulating other view controllers while you are not in it? I would have thought this worked given that they both have the Masterviewcontroller.swift as the class

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Although sometimes *possible*, it's generally not a good idea to directly manipulate one view controller's view from another view controller, as you are trying to do. Here is how I would do what you are trying to do.

First, set a segue identifier between your two view controllers by clicking on the segue in the storyboard and going to the attributes inspector. I suggest `goToMasterViewController`

In both `MasterViewController.swift` and `PurchaseViewController.swift` declare a variable `var buttonHidden = false`

In `PurchaseViewController.swift` add the following code, which will be called just before your segue to MasterViewController is performed:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "goToMasterViewController") {
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! MasterViewController
        destinationController.buttonHidden = buttonHidden
    }
}
```

When you hide the button in PurchaseViewController, also set `buttonHidden = true`

And finally in `MasterViewController.swift`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    testButton.isHidden = buttonHidden
}
```

Comment: It is sometimes **possible** to manipulate another view controller's views, but it is always a bad idea to do so. I would state it as "You should not try to manipulate another view controller's views/buttons. It's a bad idea." Then go on to explain the right way to do it.

Comment: Agreed, thank you. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, curious to why it is a bad idea to manipulate another views buttons. And thank you for the in depth explanation Austin. I will attempt this shortly

Comment: My best guess as to why it's a bad idea is that it goes against proper object oriented design principles. The scope of your button's state should be confined to the view controller class, and therefore you don't want anything outside that class to have the ability to directly manipulate the button. I'm not 100% sure this explanation is correct, and therefore welcome anyone else to join in this conversation.

Comment: And one very nit-picky comment on your code: in Swift, `FirstLetterUpperCase` naming convention is general only used for classes, modules, enums, and a few other objects. For variables, it's generally preferred to use `firstLetterLower`. I'm referring to your UIButton, which you've called `Test`. `testButton` or `testBtn` would be Swiftier :)

Comment: Hi Austin, I have just read your code in depth, and am confused by something. You are referencing PurchaseViewController.Swift and MasterViewController.swift. I only have MasterViewController.Swift, Purchase View Controllers class is MasterViewController.Swift. PlanViewControllers class is also MasterViewController.Swift

Comment: In general, each view controller should have exactly one view controller file, and each view controller file should be used by exactly one view controller. Any substantial chunks of code that are common to multiple view controller files can be placed in a separate file (to adhere to the DRY principle). Maybe I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about your project... but it seems to me like you should create another class for your second view controller. Feel free to share a link to your project if you want me to take a look.

Comment: Any luck? Or still need more clarification?